# meta forum for ROS answers?

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Recent discussions on ros-users](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/answers-ros-org-is-the-hell-td4019603.html) showed that ROS Answers is ... Hmm, let's say ... That there is room for improvement. :-)

For this reason there are "meta forums" for stack exchange Q&A's, where people are discussing the usage of the Q&A forum itself.

Example:

http://robotics.stackexchange.com/

http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/

In order to not spam the normal ROS-related Q&As with forum-related/AskBot-related questions, I'd like to suggest to implement a meta forum for ROS Answers.

What do you think?

PS: There is a related question on AskBot, but unfortunately no answer to it: http://askbot.org/en/question/6797/hosted-meta-site-linked-to-main-site/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55945/meta-forum-for-ros-answers?/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-21**:
Hi, Marcus. Isn't `ros-users` mailing list is a some sort of "meta-site" already?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-27**:
Just found out, that we are making use of GitHub issues for answers.ros.org (see [here](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org)). Altthough I like this approach, we should clearly state somewhere, which questions/problems should be asked where (answers.ros.org, ros-users, GitHub)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recent dicussions on ros-users sho that ros-users is a satisfactory place to discuss such things. Adding more places just makes it harder to track dicussions. We can handle some small surplus of meta questions and discussions both here and on ros-users currently.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-24**:
Personally, I agree with your (and @Boris) point of view. However, there have also been comments about ros-users being "high bandwidth" and other comments indicating it being too lively for some. Hence, I decided to ask this questions here.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-24**:
If more users agree with this point of view (i.e. upvotes/comments), we should clearly state somewhere, where users should ask questions and place request about ros answers, e.g. [Get Involved page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved)).

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-02-07**:
the `answers.ros.org` tag could serve as a meta tag

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-02-07**:
@2ROS0 FYI [my answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/55945/meta-forum-for-ros-answers/?answer=282042#post-id-282042).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have had a github repo [ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues) for tracking meta issues for Answers website for awhile. I assume any improvement discussion can be done there as well.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2